# Installing Jitsi software itself inside Nextcloud

Tags: nextcloud

We have a self-hosted Nextcloud software and we understand we can install integration plugin for Jitsi within Nextcloud that talks to a separately installed Jitsi instance in some other server.

However, we would like to install Jitsi software itself inside Nextcloud software.  Please let us know if it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense. You cannot install a software inside another software. What does that even mean? And why would you want to do that?

Comment: I assume what you _actually_ want to ask is whether it is possible to install that second software _one the same system_ that you installed nextcloud on. That certainly is possible. And you can then even use that jitsi instance on the same system from within your nextcloud instance using said integration plugin. Such "separately installed Jitsi instance" does not at all have to be "on another server", it _can_ be on a separate system, but nothing speaks against doing that on the same system. If that system is powerful enough, obviously.